# WebSocket is single thread only and golang is low performance with webSocket?

Tags: go, websocket

https://matttomasetti.medium.com/websocket-performance-comparison-10dc89367055

This document says that websocket uses single thread only, is that true?
And golang shows very low performance, but is this the case with servers in general situations?

I'm sorry if this is a really ignorant question.However, with my search ability, it was hard to tell if this was true.

Comment: "Is it true?" well, for this particular benchmark it obviously is. Is it relevant to anyone? Probably not.

Comment: Actually, I found two posts that I did the test on. However, the contents of the two posts are the opposite What is true?? https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/websocket-shootout, https://matttomasetti.medium.com/websocket-performance-comparison-10dc89367055

Comment: They are both true in their own context. Are you actually pushing a Go websocket server to the absolute limits, because otherwise none of this matters. Your own code is probably your bottleneck if you are even hitting performance limitations

Comment: The Go benchmark application in the article uses one goroutine per connection. The article does not provide evidence that a single goroutine per connection is responsible for the performance problem.